# activemq with camel: rate limit across all vs across one

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I am researching ActiveMQ, in particular, integrating it into my java app using Camel.

Our architecture involves queuing jobs across multiple multithreaded vms. I need in particular two kinds of rate limits:

- per vm per time period (all threads)
- per all vms per time period

Is there a way to specify these in camel, or are all rate limits implemented on a per-consumer basis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [throttler](http://camel.apache.org/throttler.html), I think you can setup the rate limit per route. As the exchange information is not share across the camel route, I don't think it can work for all vms.

Comment: Yeah, after more investigation that's basically what I was afraid of. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only way to implement this that meets the requirements (that I can imagine) is to have another process that monitors the queue. At a regular interval, it would send a message to a topic which would say whether we had exceeded the rate limit for that period of time. Any process that subscribes to the queue would have to subscribe to the topic, and when it received a message that the allotted number had been processed it would shut that route down.